# MSBUILD cannot build solution with Mixed Platforms?

Tags: c#, c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am upgrading batch file that needs to now restore nuget and build a solution that contains both c# x86 and c++ Wind32 projects -  it used to use devenv just fine before the nuget additions. The solution is 'Mixed Platforms'.  How do i do this with MSBuild?  I can't specify x86, as the Win32 c++ projects then don't get built.

This works for x64,

```
@ECHO OFF
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
ECHO Bulding for x64!!!

ECHO Building Theo.sln...
msbuild Theo.sln /t:restore /t:build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /verbosity:quiet
```

but since this is Mixed Platforms, this does NOT work!

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86
ECHO Bulding for x86!!!

ECHO Building Theo.sln...
msbuild Theo.sln /t:restore /t:build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Mixed Platforms" /verbosity:quiet
```

I get an error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Debug|MixedPlatforms" is invalid.

Comment: Why are you using `Mixed Platforms` for `x86` build?

Comment: Because C++ is Win32, it cannot be x86

Comment: You should properly organize your solution and use `win32` target for C++ projects under `x86` solution target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MSBUILD cannot build solution with Mixed Platforms?

I think you should check your **Mixed Platforms** which you created carefully.

I suggest you could create **Mixed Platforms** in this way. If you already used this way, you should check every step carefully.

**Solution**

**First of all**, remove or delete the previous Platform **Mixed Platforms**.

**1)** open menu **Build**-->**Configuration Manager**-->**Solution Platform** which will act on the whole solution.

**Also**, make sure the names are consistent and there are no spelling mistakes.

[image]

**2)** Create like this and remember to select `x86` platform.

[image]

Then use the `x86` bat file to build the project and in my side, it works well as expected.

============================

**Update 1**

Actually, when you use my solution platform which set to x86 and then enable it, it will change win32 c++ project to use `win32` platform as you expected. Rather than `x86`. You should note that.

C++ projects use Win32 as platform rather than x86. When you use my solution platform, it will change the win32 c++ projects to use `Win32` platform.

**Or** you can try to build the win32 project separately with win32 platfrom and test whether it could be built successfully.

Please check whether you have do any changes to `xxx.vcxproj` file and you should check it carefully.

[image]

**Besides**, I found that the error message `Debug|MixedPlatforms` and it uses `MixedPlatforms` rather than `Mixed Platforms` while your batch file uses `/p:Platform="Mixed Platforms"`. It is quite strange. I think you have defined the wrong name of it in your solution and you should check it carefully.

**In addition**, you can try to call `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` to test your solution.

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" x86
ECHO Bulding for x86!!!

ECHO Building test1.sln...
msbuild C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\test1\test1.sln /t:restore /t:build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Mixed Platforms"
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work either from command line.  sitll says specified solution configuration Debug|Mixed Platform is invalid.  I think nobody is considering the c++ is NOT x86, but is Win32

Comment: Actually, when you use my configuration Mixed Platform which set to x86, it always change the win32 project to use win32 platform.  Besides, can you build your project with win32 platform separately without errors?